# How to load packed (but not signed) Edge extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I know how to load unpacked Microsoft Edge extension.

Now I have my extension packed (but not signed yet) to a `.appx` file. Can I load the extension via the `.appx` file?

I tried to open the `.appx` file by double-click on it, it shows:

```
Installation failed
Reason: This one isn't signed with a trusted certificate.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install an Edge extension from a package, but it **must be** signed by the certificate which should be added to the **trusted people** store as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages). Well, I see, that you have a problem with signing, so you can try to use [this extension sample](https://github.com/alexeysidorov92/edge.echo.extension), which contains **.bat** file to build a package and sign it (Visual Studio 2015 is required - see the second line of build.bat). I have published this sample to report about [the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234322/communication-between-content-script-and-background-script-in-microsoft-edge). Hope this will help you.